# Why balls cannot be displayed when I code Pong in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am a rookie of coding Pygame. My first assignment is coding a `PONG game`. However, I found that two balls cannot displayed in screen. I don't know the reason. I will provide my code. Thanks! Also, there has an `error` at the last line. However, I just copy from the Pygame Document I don't know why it exists a `error`.

```
import pygame,sys,time

# Open a brand-new window
pygame.init()


Screen_size = (500,400)
Title = ('Pong')
Frame_Delay = 0.01
Surface= pygame.display.set_mode(Screen_size,0,0)
pygame.display.set_caption(Title)
# Set up white color for drawing balls
white=pygame.Color('white')
# Now, we start to draw two balls
pos1=(100,200)
pos2=(400,200)
rad=50
ball1=pygame.draw.circle=(Surface,white,pos1,rad,0)
ball2=pygame.draw.circle=(Surface,white,pos2,rad,0)
pygame.display.update()
# Now, define speed
speed=[2,2]
# Now, we define a loop
while ball1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
```

## The syntax error will show below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/guest-54jjJ1/Desktop/pong.py", line 24, in <module>
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
builtins.SystemExit:
```

Comment: Not really the problem, but read up on pep8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
ball1=pygame.draw.circle=(Surface,white,pos1,rad,0)
ball2=pygame.draw.circle=(Surface,white,pos2,rad,0)
```

You shouldnt be setting the function `=` to a tuple.  You should call [draw.circle()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) like this:

```
ball1 = pygame.draw.circle(Surface, white, pos1, rad, 0)
ball2 = pygame.draw.circle(Surface, white, pos2, rad, 0)
```

By the way, its really bad form to call a variable `Surface`.  That is the name of a class in `pygame`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
while ball1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

Moving the `sys.exit()` down can help in many cases.

Comment: Thank you. But I still cannot see that two balls. Can I know the reason?

Comment: pep8 is nice, but this isnt the reason its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Indenting, mate.....

```
while ball1:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
         sys.exit()
```